# shell script within a CLI program

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command-line-interface

I have a CLI program and want to create a shell script that interact with it to make it more user-friendly for end user. This program usually will run and standby at a CLI and it doesn't have syntax.

so it supposed to go something like this

```
read "question 1" input1
read "question 2" input2
run CLIprogram

#at CLI
CLI> command1 $input1

#and then command1 will ask something and the script will put the input2
Please put input 2
CLI> $input2
```

So I want the end-user only interact with the first 2 questions on my script and know nothing about the CLI. I don't need to know the output of the CLI program. Is this possible?
Thanks for any help

Kind Regards,
joe

Comment: When you call `CLIprogram` from your script, it will be executed in its own *sub-shell*. If the CLIprogram prompts for input, then you will be interacting with it directly until it completes and returns control to the script. Is that close to what you are asking?

Comment: hi David, what I need is the script will get input and the input will be passed on to the CLIprogram. for example a sqlite3 has an CLI.
so instead of end-user type all the sql command "SELECT FROM" bla bla.. I'm just gonna prompt them from the script all the value I needed and I will pass it to the sqlite3 CLI.
Of course in the case of sqlite3 we can run it without getting into the CLI by calling it with syntax. However, my CLIprogram can't be called directly and all the command can only be called within the CLI.
hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

The following is an example that uses the `mongo` cli command, it reads 2 arguments from the user and then passes it as input to the `mongo` cli. You should be able to apply the same to your cli as long as it follows standard Linux input/output patterns.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "question 1"
read input1

echo "question 2"
read input2

mongo <<EOF
use test
db.testcoll.insert({"name_str":"$input1", "age_num":$input2})
db.testcoll.find()
EOF
```

Comment: what if the $input2 is placed after command1 process $input1. please see the logic on my questions

Comment: hi, thanks for the help. i decided to use other method (open an SSH thru windows and run an autoit/macro program